# ¿Como hago un input type radio con opciones de la base de datos?

Tags: html, base-de-datos, input

Construí un tipo `"Select"` pero necesitaba un `"Radio"`, el `"Select"` trae opciones directamente de la base de datos:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
 <label for="{{ADMISSION_FIELD_TYPE_QUOTE_ID}}">Tipo de Cita</label>
 <select class="form-control select" name="{{ADMISSION_FIELD_TYPE_QUOTE_ID}}" id=" {{ADMISSION_FIELD_TYPE_QUOTE_ID}}">
    @foreach ($tiposCitas as $tipoCita)
      <option value="{{ $tipoCita->id }}"{{old(ADMISSION_FIELD_TYPE_QUOTE_ID) == $tipoCita->id ? ' selected' : '' }}> {{ $tipoCita->descripcion }} </option>
    @endforeach
 </select>
```

Así luce:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero lo necesito así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo no se construir un radio que traiga de la base de datos, si no el normal donde se añade las opciones ahí mismo como:

```
<p>Seleccione una opción:</p>
  <input type="radio" id="consulta" name="gender" value="consulta">
  <label for="consulta">Consulta</label><br>
```

Y bueno... ¿Alguien podría ayudarme? espero haberme explicado con claridad. De antemano ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al iterar los registros obtenidos de la base de datos, en lugar de generar `<option>` dentro de un `<select>`, necesitas generar `<input type="radio">`

#### Ejemplo:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <p>Seleccione una opción:</p>
  @foreach ($tiposCitas as $tipoCita)
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="{{ADMISSION_FIELD_TYPE_QUOTE_ID}}" value="{{ $tipoCita->id }}"{{old(ADMISSION_FIELD_TYPE_QUOTE_ID) == $tipoCita->id ? ' checked' : '' }}>
    {{ $tipoCita->descripcion }}
  </label>
  @endforeach
```

Comment: No puedo creer lo cerca que estaba de lograrlo, jajajaj, muchas gracias por tu respuesta me ayudaste a entender como funcionaba.

Answer (score 2):

Si te he entendido bien, lo único que tienes que hacer es extender lo que tu mismo has propuesto, es decir:

```
<p>Seleccione una opción:</p>

@foreach ($tiposCitas as $tipoCita)
<input type="radio" id="consulta-{{$tipoCita->id}}" name="EL_MISMO_NOMBRE_PARA_TODOS" value="{{ $tipoCita->id }}" {{old(ADMISSION_FIELD_TYPE_QUOTE_ID) == $tipoCita->id ? ' checked' : '' }}>
<label for="consulta-{{$tipoCita->id}}">{{ $tipoCita->descripcion }}</label>
@endforeach
```

Comment: @Marcos tienes razón, muchas gracias!

Comment: Wow realmente era muy sencillo muchisimas gracias, me ayudaste muchisimo.

Answer (score 0):

@cooper y @Marcos
Muchas gracias sus 2 respuestas me ayudaron mucho, daba por seguro que no era posible por que al investigar no apareció nada, Asi me quedo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así construí el código:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
   <label for="{{ADMISSION_FIELD_TYPE_QUOTE_ID}}">Tipo de Cita</label>
       @foreach ($tiposCitas as $tipoCita)<br>
   <input type="radio" id="{{ADMISSION_FIELD_TYPE_QUOTE_ID}}" name="{{ADMISSION_FIELD_TYPE_QUOTE_ID}}" value="{{ $tipoCita->id }}"{{old(ADMISSION_FIELD_TYPE_QUOTE_ID) == $tipoCita->id ? ' checked' : '' }}>{{ $tipoCita->descripcion }}
       @endforeach
</div>
```

Nuevamente, Muchisimas gracias.